# App webview session ou cookie

Tags: javascript, android, json, api, token

Olá, galera!

Estou criando um app (híbrido) para android, a partir do HTML5, CSS e JAVASCRIPT, como WebView.
Usarei API através do PHP usando MYSQL, trocando informações com JSON.

A minha dúvida é seguinte, a onde devo guardar o token para fazer requisição? Pois como vou pegar a identificação do cliente?

Não sei se expliquei direitinho, espero que sim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Augusto,

Você pode gerar o token no php e devolvê-lo no success do login e então passar a informá-lo em todas as demais requests.

Normalmente as requests por API fazem a checagem de autenticação por requisição, inclusive isso depende da sua lógica e do tempo de inatividade. 
Por exemplo, se você não for expirar o usuário no app até que ele faça o logout, pode criar uma tabela de relacionamento de usuário com sessão. E armazenar o token nesta tabela. Sempre que você achar o usuário nesta tabela ele está logado. E para deslogá-lo, só excluir o registro.

Se você irá utilizar 100% webview, pode armazenar os dados do cliente na sessão do javascript.

Algo parecido com isso:
`window.sessionStorage.setItem("token", "meutoken")`

Para recuperar:
`window.sessionStorage.getItem("token")`

---

Adicionalmente...

Supondo ainda que você tenha jQuery carregado e o token está no header `Authorization` pode definír como padrão em todas as requisições assim:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'Authorization': window.sessionStorage.getItem("token") }
});
```

Comment: Ericson, muito obrigado.

Aproveitando para finalizar, você acha seguro fazer requisição via URL com token ou utilizar frameworks como Auth0, Slim etc...

Comment: Augusto, sinceramente não estou familiarizado com estes frameworks. Particularmente prefiro manter o controle da lógica na própria aplicação, resolvendo as compatibilidades de escalabilidade, mas é claro que vc vai precisar se preocupar com a segurança neste modelo (por exemplo uso de RSA na criptografia do token) , ja nos frameworks devem ter se preocupado bastante, principalmente nos open sources com o apoio da comunidade. Isso também depende do seu projeto inclusive com outros meios de autenticação-supondo que o seu maior publico seja Android, poderia utilizar a autenticação do Google.